# showCloseButton react-bootstrap-sweetalert not displayed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert

I am using lib `react-bootstrap-sweetalert` to handle popup. So far everything works great. But, when I try to implement one of their props, `showCloseButton` - described [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-sweetalert#propsshowclosebutton) -, the close button not displayed anywhere in my alert. Then, I try to copy-paste the code in their example [here](http://djorg83.github.io/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/), and here is the code:

```
<SweetAlert
  custom
  showCancel
  showCloseButton
  confirmBtnText="Yes"
  cancelBtnText="No"
  confirmBtnBsStyle="primary"
  cancelBtnBsStyle="default"
  customIcon="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/djorg83/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/master/demo/assets/thumbs-up.jpg"
  title="Do you like thumbs?"
  onConfirm={this.onConfirm}
  onCancel={this.onCancel}
>
  You will find they are up!
</SweetAlert>
```

the "x" close button still did not displayed in my alert. Then, I try to show the alert at their example, the close button displayed! What goes wrong here? I've copy-paste, it is not working. But, it is working on their example site. Anyway, I am using version `^4.4.1` of `react-bootstrap-sweetalert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the example is for its latest version. Please update to the latest!

It's because I can't see the option `showCloseButton` in v4.4.1: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-sweetalert/v/4.4.1

Comment: yeah, I figure it out after see the github repo again. Also, if anyone read this and successfully show the close button but its not clickable, I bet its because the title of the alert is override the button. Try to give z-index to the close button will help